# Toggling Menu Items in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have created a class which extends JavaFX's MenuBar that creates a menu bar for my application.

By default I won't specialized operations, like opening/saving a file and running a simulation, to be disabled (and they are). When a user runs the app they can select an item in the menu File>New>, and based on which component they select it will toggle on the appropriate menu options.

I was planning on doing this by having each component give a list of which items it toggles on, and then activating the appropriate items when the component is created.

However, I cannot access the list of menus from within in a function (am trying to do it with `this.getMenus()` but from within the function the only function that is recognized it `this.getClass()`).

Does anyone know why I cannot call `getMenus()` and how I could get access to it?
Alternatively, if you have a better idea for how I can toggle these menu items, I'd love to hear. I don't think this is a good way to do it, but it is the best idea we have come up with.

```
private void fileNew()
{
    Menu fileNew = new Menu("New");
    menuFile.getItems().add(fileNew);

    for(String k: CLHM.keySet())
    {
        CComponent comp = CLHM.get(k);
        if(comp.supportedFeatures().contains((new SupportsNew())))
        {
            MenuItem i = new MenuItem(comp.getName());
            fileNew.getItems().add(i);

            i.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    CComponent ctemp = CLHM.get(i.getText());

                    ArrayList<String> menuItems = (ArrayList) ctemp.getMenuItems();
                    for (String s : menuItems)
                    {
                        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s).useDelimiter("\\s>\\s");
                        String menu = scanner.next();
                        //Menu temp = this.getMenus();
                        /*
                         Here the program will parse the string of the 
                         Menu path (e.g. File>Open) and activate the
                         relevant item, if it exists.
                         */


                    }

                    borderPane.setCenter((Node) ctemp);
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What does `menuFile.getItems()` do?

Comment: very suboptimal approach! go the clean path, separate out the logic into a model, which decides which actions are allowed based on whatever conditions, then bind the menuItems' disabled to the appropriate properties of the model

Comment: @Sedrick It adds the item under the File option in the menu bar. Because the namespace for file is already cluttered I have had to choose weird names.

Comment: @kleopatra can you explain what that means?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `this` inside an anonymous class, it actually refers to the anonymous class instance. So in your case, `this` is an instance of `EventHandler`, which is why there are so little methods that you can call (because it is an interface type).

What you are looking for is `YourExtendedMenuBar.this.getMenus()`. This will tell the compiler that you are looking for the enclosing instance. Alternatively, you can simply drop the `this` keyword (i.e. `getMenus()`). Doing so will allow you to use/call any accessible members of the anonymous class and its enclosing class.

On the side note, if you replaced that anonymous class with a lambda expression, then `this` would have meant `YourExtendedMenuBar`. It is not possible to access any members of the class that the lambda expression represents, at least not directly.

P.S. I have no idea what your toggling is all about, so I can't answer until I figured out what you mean.